# Accessing Administration Console in TFS

Tags: tfs

I have TFS installed in the server.I need to access the administration client localy not to every time login to server to use the admin console.Is there client version available that I can install in my machine (admin cosole) so that I can connect to server and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will need to logon the server and use the Tfs Management Console.

Comment: Thanks Duat.That explains.I was searching for some tool.