# Client tool on local machine for TFS administration

Tags: tfs

Is there a tool available that I can install on my machine for TFS administrative tasks without having to log in to the TFS server? I found one same question - [Accessing Administration Console in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315451/accessing-administration-console-in-tfs) - but it was from 2011. We are using TFS 2012 and Visual studio 2008.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *TFS administrative tasks without having to log in to the TFS server*? For me the term *TFS administrative task* is tasks done the server.

Comment: I meant tasks which I can do from my machine (local) - like undo checkout files checked out by other team members. One of the team member left and has some file checked out on his machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the TFS Admin Console can only be run on the server (unlike most other admin tools like SSMS which can be run remotely).

We (the ALM MVP's) have asked Microsoft for this capability in the past, so they know about it, it just hasn't been a priority to implement yet.

Comment: Hi Dylan, i need to undo checkout some files that are checked out by another user. I think this is an administrative task that needs higher privileges and that was in my mind when I asked that question. Some answers on other related SO questions suggest to run tf.exe. Do I need to install team explorer on the server to run this utility?

Answer (score 0):

Tfs sidekicks will cover some of your request, the tfs administration tool will also help with user accounts. Admin tool can found on codeplex